# Typescript error This condition will always return 'true' since the types have no overlap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I having this condition on a form  group:

```
if((age>17 && (this.frType=="Infant")) 
|| (age>40 && this.frType=="Grandchild")
|| (age<=5 && 
   (this.frType!="Child" 
   || this.frType!="Infant" 
   || this.frType!="Grandchild" || this.frType!="Cousin")))
```

It contain 3 main conditions:

1. If a person aged 17, cannot be set to `infant`
2. If a person is bigger than 40, he cannot be a `grandchild`
3. If a person is less than 5 years, he should be `child`, `infant`, `grandchild` or `cousin`.

If one of these conditions is true, I will send an error message.

The error I am receiving is:

> [ts] This condition will always return 'true' since the types
>   '"Child"' and '"Infant"' have no overlap. [2367]

On this part of the `if` condition`:

```
|| this.frType!="Infant" || this.frType!="Grandchild" || this.frType!="Cousin")))
```

I am using the exact condition in a different component, and it does not show an error.

```
if((age>17 && (this.family_relation_type=="Infant")) 
|| (age>40 && this.family_relation_type=="Grandchild")
|| (age<=5 && 
   (this.family_relation_type!="Child" || 
    this.family_relation_type!="Infant" || 
    this.family_relation_type!="Grandchild" || 
    this.family_relation_type!="Cousin")))
```

Here is how I am calculating the age in both components:

```
let timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.formGroup.controls['dob'].value);
let age = Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24))/365);
```

Comment: happens while having implicit value comparisons. Use "===" and "!==" instead of "==" & "!=".

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Consider the standalone expression:

```
(this.frType!="Child" || this.frType!="Infant")
```

If `frType` is `Child`, the second part will be true, so the expression will evaluate to `true`. If `frType` is `Infant`, then the first part will be true, so the expression will evaluate to `true`. If `frType` is *neither* `Child` nor `Infant`, then the first part will be true, and the expression will, again, evalute to `true` - the logic is faulty, it'll always resolve to `true`.

(If you add additional `||` conditions for `Grandchild` and `Cousin`, the same thing keeps happening - it'll always resolve to `true`)

Either use `&&` instead:

```
|| (age<=5 && (
   this.frType!="Child" 
   && this.frType!="Infant" 
   && this.frType!="Grandchild"
   && this.frType!="Cousin"
 ))
```

Or, to make the logic easier to follow, you might consider using an array, and use `.includes`:

```
const kidsFiveAndUnder = ['Child', 'Infant', 'Grandchild', 'Cousin'];
// ...
|| (age <= 5 && !kidsFiveAndUnder.includes(this.frType))
```

Answer (score 17):

*Maybe i can help someone with this.*

In my case the error was triggered by:

`*ngIf="fooArray.length === 0"`

so i modified it to be:

`*ngIf="fooArray.length < 1"`

Makes no sense to me, but it works.

Comment: It's better to leave out the Angular `*ngIf` stuff, it's just noise that's not relevant to the TypeScript issue at hand.

Comment: I know it is not part of the TS issue, Im just trying to help anyone with the same scenario.

Answer (score 10):

I struggled with this problem recently. Sharing my experience here

Basically IDE does not allow to compare an object.enum with a string. As a solution, a method in the component.ts is added to compare the enum

Details :

```
export enum Status {
     NEW,
     PROGRESS,
     FINISHED
}

export interface Model {
   id : number;
   name : string;
   status : Status
}
```

Now in the component.html, I was trying to compare the model status

```
<div *ngFor="let m of modelItems" >
      <i *ngIf="m.status === 'NEW'" class="icon-new"></i>
</div>

Error : This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Status' and 'string' have no overlap.ngtsc(2367)
```

I also tried defining the status enum in the component.ts and used that for comparison

```
public StatusEnum = Status; 

<div *ngFor="let m of modelItems" >
      <i *ngIf="StatusEnum[m.status] === 'NEW'" 
        class="icon-new"></i>
</div>
```

With the above solution, there is no IDE error, but the condition never true, as the enum[value] give a numeric value.

The next option I tried was as follows

```
<div *ngFor="let m of modelItems" >
      <i *ngIf="m.status=== StatusEnum[StatusEnum.NEW]" class="icon-new"></i>
    </div>
```

But ended up with the error again in the IDE

```
Error : This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Status' and 'string' have no overlap.ngtsc(2367)
```

Finally what solved the issue it implement a method in the component.ts

**Solution**

component.ts

```
public StatusEnum = Status; //To refer in the HTML

 checkStatus(m: Model, status: Status): boolean {
    return Status[m.status] as unknown === status;
  }
```

Note : Status[m.status] as unknown

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let m of modelItems" >
       <i *ngIf="checkStatus(m,StatusEnum.NEW)" 
       class="icon-new"></i>
  </div>
```

Comment: Pretty good answer. You may want to see a cleaner answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54401981/11322237

Answer (score 6):

**Define the data types of all your variables explicitly.**

For example, this code has the same error mentioned in the thread title and I fixed by defining the data types of the variables explicitly.

From:

```
const selectedLangCulture = "en"; // or "ar-SA"
const direction = "rtl";
const languageChanged =
  (direction === "rtl" && selectedLangCulture === "en") ||
  (direction === "ltr" && selectedLangCulture === "ar-SA");
```

To:

```
const selectedLangCulture: string = "en"; // Put the datatype string.
const direction: string = "rtl"; // Put the datatype string.
const languageChanged =
  (direction === "rtl" && selectedLangCulture === "en") ||
  (direction === "ltr" && selectedLangCulture === "ar-SA");
```

Comment: Strange but very good. It solved my problem thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using a type named `type` for the button element with `React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'button'>`

```
type ButtonProps = {
  type?: 'submit' | 'button' | 'link'; // ❌
} & React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'button'>;
```

the `type` was overridden because `React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'button'>` had a `type` in it also. I replaced it with `elementType` and the problem is solved.

```
type ButtonProps = {
  elementType?: 'submit' | 'button' | 'link'; // ✅
} & React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'button'>;
```

Answer (score 2):

it look like typescript **help to "simplify the Logic"**

- so it help remove the unnecessary Logic code.

- '||' mean **one true -> all true**, so **comparison after is not necessary**
- '&&' mean one false -> all false, so comparison is a must

go trough the code below will have better understanding.

[image: code run on js typescript]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I simply had to rebuild my app because the type definitions got briefly out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, In typescript base architecture, The most common error will come when you do not have a proper type conversion while comparing or converting data.

1. Check the data type that you are manipulating.
2. The Data coming from the request is correctly converted to the desired one.
3. Check the conditions of statements.