# Angular2 - How to use string enums with *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, angular7

How do I pass `enum` to a function when I use `*ngIf` in Angular?

I have the follow code:

```
export enum RoleType {
    User='User',
    Admin='Admin'
}
```

**component function**

```
public hasAccess(role: RoleType) {
   //check role type and return true or false
}
```

**component html**

```
<div id="adminDiv" *ngIf="hasAccess('Admin')">
</div>
```

When I build this, it keeps complaining. It cannot convert the string to the enum, is there a way around this?

Comment: ``hasAccess(RoleType.Admin)``, and note if you want use this enum in template you need to assign it to some public property like ``RoleType = RoleType``.

Comment: tried it - doesn't like it...

Comment: Why hard code a parameter in the template? Just create a function that checks to see if the user is an admin.

Comment: @Buczkowski Perhaps you can answer this question with an example, because that is a fairly good alternative.

Comment: @Silvermind veben just did.

Comment: @Hypenate No he didn't, you are misinterprating Buczkowski's comment. That's why I suggested him to create an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a constant in an Angular 2 component and service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237561/how-to-access-a-constant-in-an-angular-2-component-and-service)

Comment: I know that this is a somewhat old question, but can you accept @Dejazmach's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61442911/4032703)? His answer solved it for me.

Answer (score 33):

Here is a much cleaner way of doing this. Do the following in your component.ts

```
allRoleTypes = RoleType;
```

and in your html

```
*ngIf="role===allRoleTypes.User"
```

You don't need to write any method.

Comment: Much cleaner indeed.

Comment: Cleaner but still horrible (having to duplicate an enum as a local variable in every place it's used... yuck!)

Comment: @jeancallisti That's not duplication, duplication is when you have to write the enum multiple times. Here you are just using it. Any other options? We are listening.

Comment: @Dejazmach suit yourself, if you think it's normal to have to copy-paste a foreign and hard-to-understand line of code in every place where you want to use a given enum, I won't fight you. TL;DR: YUCK!

Comment: @jeancallisti tell me what to do, what is the better approach? Is it saying "Yuck"? If it is, no thank you, I don't need it.

Comment: @Dejazmach the "yuck" is not directed at you, it's directed at Angular. If there's no better way then there's no better way, but I'm allowed to mock the convoluted gotchas of Angular.

Comment: @jeancallisti Ahhh, good point. Actually there are ways of doing this using Subjects but I think that is beyond the scope of this question. Maybe the right way of answering to this question is "No, that is not how you should implement security, learn and understand Subjects and Observables (RXJS) first". I think Angular is the best by the way.

Answer (score 24):

As @Buczkowski suggested, you can do it like this:

```
export enum RoleType {
    User = 'User',
    Admin = 'Admin'
}
```

### component

```
RoleType = RoleType; // This way you can access its properties from the template.

public hasAccess(role: RoleType) {
    //check role type and return true or false
}
```

### component html

```
<div id="adminDiv" *ngIf="hasAccess(RoleType.Admin)">
</div>
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-he9sxa)

Answer (score 3):

Get it as a string, then convert it to the RoleType.

```
public hasAccess(role: string): boolean {
const roleAsEnum: RoleType = RoleType[role];

return ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But doesn't this just makes the enum redundant then??

Comment: I suppose it would :) I would lean more to the idea of R. Richards.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use function with parameter in the template, but do something like that:

Declare a var `isAdmin` in your `.ts` file, and initialize it at the creation of the component, checking if the user is admin:

```
isAdmin = false;
ngOnInit() {
    this.isAdmin = this.checkIfUserAdmin(...)
}
```

Use it in the `*ngIf`:

```
<div id="adminDiv" *ngIf="isAdmin">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use another var, something like **AdminTest** in your .ts file, and set a value to it at the `ngOnInit` hook.

you should have something like :

**.ts**:

```
AdminTest = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.AdminTest = this.checkRole()
}

checkRole() {
    // ...
}
```

**.html**:

```
<div id="adminDiv" *ngIf="AdminTest"></div>
```

Comment: You added an answer similar to @veben's answer

Comment: yes i guess we where all. rigth, i didn't see is answer before

Answer (score 0):

The Error appears because you are passing String when an enum is expected. As others have suggested, there are multiple ways to handle it and one of them is:

```
  private hasRole(role: string) {
    console.log(role == RoleType.admin);
    console.log(role == RoleType.user);
  }
```