# Check file upload type in PrimeNG and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am trying to restrict the type of file that a user can upload. I can only allow pdf and doc.
My HTML has the following

```
<input #pdfUploadID type="file" id="fileUploadID" formControlName="fileUploadID" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files, 'id')" accept=".pdf,.doc">
```

Doing this alone still allows a user to change the allowed types on the browser popup window as seen below
[image]

So I have custom code that checks the type of file after the user uploads like below

```
if (this.fileToUploadID.type !== 'application/pdf') {
   this.isPDFId = false;
} else { this.isPDFId = true; }
```

My problem is when I try to add more type to the if statement like this that I get the following error

> This condition will always return 'true' since the types
>   '"application/pdf"' and '"application/msword"' have no overlap.

```
 if ((this.fileToUploadID.type !== 'application/pdf')||(this.fileToUploadID.type !== 'application/msword')) {
    console.log("file type: "+this.fileToUploadID.type);
    this.isPDFId = false;
 } else { this.isPDFId = true; }
```

Any ideas what I should add?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript error This condition will always return 'true' since the types have no overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719693/typescript-error-this-condition-will-always-return-true-since-the-types-have-n)

Comment: @mpro I did see that but it does not deal with file types

Comment: What is the type of `fileUploadID`?

Comment: @mpro It is declared as `fileToUploadID: File = null`

Comment: Could you please provide the `File` interface/class details?

Comment: @mpro That is coming directly from PrimeNG and looks like this

`interface File extends Blob {
    readonly lastModified: number;
    readonly name: string;
}`



`declare var File: {
    prototype: File;
    new(fileBits: BlobPart[], fileName: string, options?: FilePropertyBag): File;
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked PrimeNG documentation about `File` interface and it looks that `File.type` is typed as string. It looks like you might assign different type value to that property, however it is hard to say without full component preview.

Just had similar error comparing string to number:

```
value === 1 ? true : false
```

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and
>   '1' have no overlap.ts(2367)

Changing above to below removed error:

```
value === '1' ? true : false
```

If you don't find the reason of your problem try to transform value  to string using `.toString()` while comparing:

```
this.fileToUploadID.type.toString() === 'application/pdf' && this.fileToUploadId.type.toString() === 'application/msword' ? true : false;
```

However this should be also solved by using non-strict comparison operators, which @StefanN suggested.

Answer (score 0):

just replace your if-statement with the following:

```
this.isPDFId = this.fileToUploadID.type === 'application/pdf' && this.fileToUploadId.type === 'application/msword' ? true : false;
```

Comment: I get the following in my editor `This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"application/pdf"' and '"application/msword"' have no overlap.`

Comment: I see. Do you know what type `this.fileToUploadId.type` is? Otherwise, you can try to use `==` in stead of `===`

Comment: It is of type File as declared like this `fileToUploadID: File = null;`

Changing it to "==" makes no difference

Answer (score -1):

```js
fileTypes: any = [
   {type: 'application/msword', name: 'Doc'},
   {type: 'application/pdf', name: 'Pdf'}
];
fileType: string;

handleFileInput(event){
  const files = event.target.files;
  const mimeType = files[0].type;
  
  if(mimeType !== this.fileType) {
    alert(`please select a ${this.fileType} file`);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileUploadID" (change)="handleFileInput($event)" accept=".pdf,.doc"> 

<select [(ngModel)]='fileType'>
  <options *ngFor="let type of fileTypes">{{type.name}}</options>
</select>
```

Comment: Not really in the same context of the question. The sample also doesn't work.