# This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string[]' and 'string' have no overlap. ts(2367)

Tags: angular, typescript

I was playing with Angular today when this error appeared. I read the accepted answer on [Typescript error This condition will always return 'true' since the types have no overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719693/typescript-error-this-condition-will-always-return-true-since-the-types-have-n?answertab=votes#tab-top), but I don't know what it means.

Template:

```html
<div class="container">
    Paste your text here: <textarea #count width="150" height="150"></textarea><br>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" (click)=check(count.value)>Count</button>
    <br>
    <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```

Component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// import { checkServerIdentity } from 'tls'; i don't exist!

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  check(text:string) {
    var counts:string[];
    counts = text.split(" ");
    let resultid = document.getElementById("result");
    if (counts === "" /* here error */) {
      // where i left over
    }
  }

}
```

Error:

```
This condition will always return \'false\' since the types \'string\[\]\' and \'string\' have no overlap. ts(2367)
```

Comment: `counts` is an array of strings and `""` is a string, so there's no point at all comparing them. They'll never be equal. Just write `if (false) {` or remove the block entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `counts` yourself as `string[]`, and then you're trying to compare it with an empty string. An array of strings is never equal to *any* string.

I'm not sure which part you find confusing. The error couldn't be clearer: you're trying to compare an array of strings with a string. These two will never be equal, so the condition `counts === ""` will always evaluate to `false`, which is probably a mistake, so TypeScript is rightfully telling you to pay more attention. It doesn't make sense to write a conditional `if` where the condition is always `false` -- that code will never run, and therefore you either need to remove the whole block or to change the condition.

Comment: thanks  
i realized i just needed to change "counts" to "text" in the if

Comment: so counts == "" or counts.length === 0?